# NodeJS Nan C++ bind nested object to addon instance

Tags: c++, node.js, v8

In a C++ NodeJS project I'm currently working on, I want to have an object which contains a nested object, like

```
console.log(object.myObject); // { [keys: string]: any }
```

Without binding objects to properties my addon is working very well. I create the Instance with

```cpp
auto ctor = Nan::New<v8::FunctionTemplate>(New);
auto ctorInst = ctor->InstanceTemplate();
```

And bind the object to the class instance like

```cpp
v8::Local<v8::Object> obj = Nan::New<v8::Object>();
ctorInst->Set(Nan::New("myObject").ToLocalChecked(), obj);
```

which prints the following when executing the JS code (create an instance of the C++ extension).

> # Fatal error in , line 0
>
> # Check failed: !value_obj->IsJSReceiver() || value_obj->IsTemplateInfo().

On the other hand binding primitives (number, string, etc.) works flawlessly.

```cpp
ctorInst->Set(Nan::New("myObject").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Number>(42));
```

Do you have got any suggestions? Thanks and cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All templates (Including InstanceTemplate's) can only have other templates, or primitives, in them. As you see, `IsTemplateInfo` was false, when it should have been true. A similar question was asked and answered [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=4997). Simply make an [ObjectTemplate](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-0.8/db/d5f/classv8_1_1_object_template.html) and then populate it like you were doing with the `FunctionTemplate`.

Only when the Template is instantiated (with `GetFunction`), can you populate it with real objects.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Nicholas' answer I'd like to add the following.

**Instance**

Simply replace the `v8::Object` with `v8::ObjectTemplate`. Set properties to the object template and bind the template to the addon instance.

```cpp
v8::Local<v8::ObjectTemplate> objTemplate = Nan::New<v8::ObjectTemplate>();
objTemplate->Set(Nan::New("prop").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Number>(42));
ctorInst->Set(Nan::New("myObject").ToLocalChecked(), objTemplate);
```

Now you are able to use

```
console.log(addonInstance.myObject); // { prop: 42 }
```

**Prototype**

If you want to bind functions to the object, create an object template like above. Then create a function template from an existing cpp function, and bind it to an object property of the object template. Then create a template on the addon instances prototype.

```cpp
v8::Local<v8::ObjectTemplate> objTemplate = Nan::New<v8::ObjectTemplate>();
objTemplate->Set(Nan::New("prop").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Number>(42));

auto fn = Nan::New<v8::FunctionTemplate>(setup);
objTemplate->Set(Nan::New("setup").ToLocalChecked(), fn);
Nan::SetPrototypeTemplate(ctor, "myObj", objTemplate);
```

and the setup function is simply

```cpp
NAN_METHOD(YourClass::setup) {
  info.GetReturnValue().Set(Nan::New<v8::String>("Hello world").ToLocalChecked());
}
```

The console output would be

```
console.log(addonInstance.myObject) // { prop: 42, setup: [Function: setup] }
```